# Insertar un sub-documento dentro de un sub-documento Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Actualmente tengo un objeto así:

```
{
  _id: 5ab5051ec97a4202984f2973,
  student_code: "1234567890",
  name: "myname",
  lastname: "mylastname",
  areas: []
}
```

Con mongoose puedo insertar un sub-documento en `areas` así:

```
.post(function(req,res){
  Imagen.findById(req.params.id, function(err,imagen){
     res.locals.imagen.areas.push({
           area: req.body.area, //Objeto a insertar
           dependencies: [] //Array para después insertar sub-documents
     });
     res.locals.imagen.save(function(err){
        if(!err){
           res.render("app/imagenes/show",{imagen:imagen});
           console.log()
        }else{
           res.render("app/imagenes/"+imagen.id+"/edit",{imagen:imagen});
           console.log(err)
        }
     })
   })
})
```

Busco el objeto que necesito usando `Imagen.findById`, luego elijo el array al que voy a pasarle el sub-documento usando `res.locals.imagen.areas.push` y al finalizar la inserción del sub-documento me queda algo así:

```
{
  _id: 5ab5051ec97a4202984f2973,
  student_code: "1234567890",
  name: "myname",
  lastname: "mylastname",
  areas: [
           {
            _id: 5a1d53a2e8612902034c17a0
            area: "myarea", 
            dependencies: [] //Aquí quiero insertar sub-documentos
           },
           {
            _id: 5a1d53a2e8612302034c17b9
            area: "myareax", 
            dependencies: [] //Aquí quiero insertar sub-documentos
           }...
         ] 
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿como puedo insertar sub-documentos en el array `dependencies` escogiendo un objeto de `areas` por el `_id`?

Es decir: ¿como hago cuando quiero insertar un sub-documento a el array `dependencies` del objeto que tenga el `_id 5a1d53a2e8612902034c17a0` si no sé la ubicación del objeto dentro del array `areas`?

de antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: Y probaste con `res.locals.imagen.areas[0].dependencies.push`?

Comment: @amenadiel primero que todo muchas gracias por tu comentario. 
Creo que no especifiqué bien mi caso, en mi pregunta olvidé especificar que son muchos objetos dentro del array  `areas` y no conozco la ubicación del objeto dentro del array

Comment: se que no corresponde hacer esto, pero puedes revisar mi código? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676875/mongoose-connect-two-collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de insertar el sub documento buscando el objeto por el `_id` es:

```
 .post(function(req,res){
    Imagen.findById(req.params.id, function(err,imagen){
       res.locals.imagen.areas.id(_id /*pasar el id del objeto*/).dependencies.push({
         //objeto a insertar
    });
    res.locals.imagen.save(function(err){
       if(!err){
          res.render("app/imagenes/show",{imagen:imagen});
          console.log()
       }else{
          res.render("app/imagenes/"+imagen.id+"/edit",{imagen:imagen});
          console.log(err)
       }
    })
  })
})
```